# Map list from dictionaries

Tags: python, list, dictionary, pandas

I am new to python and have looked at numerous pages for this.

I know pandas data frames have this mapping functionlity:

```
dictionary = {a:1, b:2, c:6}

df['col_name'] = df.col_name.map(dictionary) #df is a pandas dictionary
```

How do I do something similar for lists, i.e.,

```
mapped_list = list_to_be_mapped.map(dictionary)
```

where in

```
list_to_be_mapped = [a,a,b,c,c,a]
mapped_list       = [1,1,2,6,6,1]
```

Comment: Should your `mapped_list` be `[1, 1, 2, 6, 6, 1]` according to your dicitionary?

Comment: Yes, I have implemented the changes. It was a small typo. This doesn't change the answer though! Thank You.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You can use the `dictionary`'s `get` function

```
list(map(dictionary.get, list_to_be_mapped))
```

Answer (score 6):

IIUC you could use simple `list comprehension` for that:

```
[dictionary[key] for key in list_to_be_mapped]

In [51]: [dictionary[key] for key in list_to_be_mapped]
Out[51]: [1, 1, 2, 6, 6, 1]
```

If you prefer `pandas` solution you could convert your `list_to_be_mapped` to Series and then use the same as in your example:

```
s = pd.Series(list_to_be_mapped)

In [53]: s
Out[53]:
0    a
1    a
2    b
3    c
4    c
5    a
dtype: object

In [55]: s.map(dictionary).tolist()
Out[55]: [1, 1, 2, 6, 6, 1]
```

Answer (score 2):

If you only want to map those values actually in your dictionary I would suggest the following:

```py
dictionary = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
list_to_be_mapped = ['a', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'a']
[dictionary.get(a) if dictionary.get(a) else a for a in list_to_be_mapped]
```

which returns

```py
[1, 1, 2, 'c', 'c', 1]
```